# ember.js - extract distinct properties from array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

lets say I have the following array, and this is used in my controller

```
songs = [
  {trackNumber: 4, title: 'Ob-La-Di, Ob-La-Da', genre: 'pop'},
  {trackNumber: 2, title: 'Back in the U.S.S.R.', genre: 'rock'},
  {trackNumber: 3, title: 'Glass Onion', genre: 'pop'},
];
```

I would like to have a property on my controller that returns an array of unique genres

eg

```
genres: function() {
  ...
}...
```

and in this case would return

```
['pop', 'rock']
```

is there some elegant way to do this with ember, using computed properties an or observers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My original answer is at the bottom, but the latest Ember releases provide a really nice new solution for this:

```
genres: Ember.computed.mapBy('songs', 'genre'),
uniqueGenres: Ember.computed.uniq('genres'),
```

References: [mapBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_mapBy) and [uniq](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_uniq). Computed property macros are great =)

previous answer:

```
genres: function() {
  return this.get('songs').map(function(song){
    return song.genre
  }).filter(function(genre, index, arr){
    return arr.indexOf(genre) == index // throw away any instances which are not first
  })
}.property('songs'),
```

note, I'm leveraging 'modern' array functions such as map and filter here, if you need to support older browsers, you'll need to shim those or write this another way. The filter I used for removing duplicates is the first that occurred to me, it's probably not very performant and if you've already loaded a library with a unique function (like [underscore.uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)), you should use that.

Very little of this is Ember specific of course, the `.property('songs')` on the end is literally all you need to specify that this is a computed property, which will be cached and recomputed if songs changes (assumes Ember 1.0)

References:
MDN for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)